# The second flex item's elements should also line up side-by-side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2a2c577e07.js"></script>
<div class="parent-flex">
  <div class="class1">Class 1</div>
  <div class="class2">
    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3140/3506456511_43787ce7e6.jpg" alt="">
    <h4> The author | </h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>The dummy text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
}    
.class2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

SITUATION: .class2 is the 2nd child of a parent, which is a flex.
.class 2 has items like
img
h2
ul with fontawesome items
p

I want all the items to align in one line. is there any flex propert that can do this trick in short or may be any non flex property method (method should be easy to be build for responsiveness)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `display: flex` to both `class2` and `ul`, all elements and their children will line up side-by-side.

Why you need to add `display: flex` multiple times is because it only affects 1 level down, so in your original code, it is only the `class1` and `class2` elements that becomes flex items and lines up horizontally.

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.class2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*margin-left: auto;*/    /*  temp. removed, uncomment if all
                                its elements should align right  */ 
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2a2c577e07.js"></script>
<div class="parent-flex">

  <div class="class1">Class 1</div>
  <div class="class2">
    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3140/3506456511_43787ce7e6.jpg" alt="">
    <h4> The author | </h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>The dummy text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: means img, h2, p everything needs to give display: flex, Right? actually i want a situation like [this](https://www.screencast.com/t/XmWbplLCTla)

Comment: @AdiYogi No, only elements with children where the children stacks vertical needs a `display: flex` of its own, as your `class2` and `ul`, not the `p` since it has only text.

Comment: @AdiYogi I will make a simple fiddle how to do the actual layout your linked image looks like. Give me a few minutes...

Comment: @AdiYogi Take a look at this fiddle, does it help: https://jsfiddle.net/dpu1o5h1/

Comment: sir, can we bring the <p></p> → downward like this → https://www.screencast.com/t/XmWbplLCTla

Comment: @AdiYogi Yes, will have a look later, need to drive kids, will show you when I get back

Comment: thanks, sir, please take care of the family members especially kids.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `flex` property to the second child also.

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.class2 {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2a2c577e07.js"></script>
<div class="parent-flex">
  <div class="class1">Class 1</div>
  <div class="class2">
    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3140/3506456511_43787ce7e6.jpg" alt="">
    <h4> The author | </h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>The dummy text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```